# Как удалить ненужные символы из документа?

Tags: python, dataframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую данные для обучения и мне нужно избавиться от ненужной информации, а конкретно от XX/XX/XXXX или от XXXX XXXX XXXXX.
Я использовал регулярные выражения, которые удаляют числа и другие объекты, которые не являются буквенными, также использовал функцию "стоп слов". Как мне лучше всего избавиться от X-ов?

```
def tokenLemmat(text):
    tokens = [word for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)] #Исправить
    filtered_tokens = []
    for token in tokens:
        if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', token):
            filtered_tokens.append(token)
    lem = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(t) for t in filtered_tokens]
    return lem

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
```

Comment: добавьте `"XX/XX/XXXX"` и `"XXXX"` в стоп-слова ;)

Comment: Там еще есть XX/XX или просто XX, все вариации не пересчитать в 150 000 данных, как-то можно иначе?

Comment: Ну сделайте регулярку, которая два и более `X` подряд удаляет. Останутся дроби, ну их вы и так я так понимаю чистите потом всё-равно.

Comment: Судя по примеру данных на картинке `"XX"` и `"XXXX"` - покрывают все варианты